# Difference between these two C conditions

Tags: c

I was just wondering what the difference is between

```
    if(matrix[i][x] && matrix[i][x] + length > matrix[i][y]){}
```

and

```
    if(matrix[i][x] > matrix[i][y] && matrix[i][x] + length > matrix[i][y]){}
```

?
I was running test cases on my program and these two statements were the cause of the difference, in some test cases they both produced the same answer but in some they don't. Are they processed differently? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first says `if(matrix[i][x] != 0 && matrix[i][x] + length > matrix[i][y]){}`

Comment: ohhh, thank you so much

Comment: Um... They are obviously different. Don't you see the difference?

Comment: Yes they will be processed differently on the basis of precedence of operator. Use braces carefully.

Comment: AnT, yeah i see it now, I'm not used to using conditions without specifying what I'm checking so when i saw this i got confused, but then i remembered that you can check for zero like that, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first tests if `matrix[i][x]` is non-zero.  The second tests if it is greater than `matrix[i][y]`.

`>` is not distributive; that is, `a && b > c` does not mean `a > c` AND `a > b`; the `a` and the `b > c` are completely separate expressions.

Comment: Thank you for answering!